# How to change year of datetime object in a pandas dataframe column to choosen year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to change only the years from a datetime object, but I wish to change it to year **2024**. I have `pandas` dataframe with a column named `Hired Date`. The date data was converted to `datetime` object:

```py
df_dash['Hired Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dash['Hired Date'])
```

If I use `DateOffset`, I can only change the year by certain increments. I wish to change them all to 2024:

```py
annual_review_data= df_dash['Hired Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
```

If I use `mask`, also does not work. The years remained the same:

```py
df_annual_review['Hired Date'].mask(df_annual_review['Hired Date'].dt.year !=2024, df_annual_review['Hired Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2024))
```

Also, I tried using arithmetics, and does not work.

```py
df_annual_review["Hired Date"] - pd.offsets.YearBegin(normalize=True)
```

This is the expected output:

```py
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
            ID        Full_Name         Hired Date    Annual Review
1   456-78-5612       Mario             2004-09-06    2024-09-06
2   343-09-6781      Aspirineta         2021-09-08    2024-09-08
```

I wish to change only the years to **2024**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell me those are not social security numbers in your data...

Comment: `pandas` probably uses standard module  `datetime` and it should have `.replace(year=...)`

Comment: maybe use `year=` instead of `years=` - `df_dash['Hired Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year=2024)`

Comment: Hi. These id are fantasy SSN , created for me for the post. No real personal data. Thanks